# How to customize the appearance of the address view in Kaddressbook?

Tags: 11.10, kubuntu, ubuntu-font-family, kaddressbook

I am impaired by my eyesight and have to set the fonts quite big to work with KDE. Kaddressbook seems to ignore the settings so that I have the contact list with big letters to choose a contact but I can't see the contact infomation to the right. Because it's so small.

Where to change the adress preview window?

(this has always been ok, but now after KDE 4.7.1 it's a mess - I don't understand why there is always regression with every new version ... !)

Comment: KDE 4.8.1 now - still no change ...

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions on filing a bug report are here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).